# Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on event maker

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an event maker on Wordpress. I'm having this error message, maybe is because I updated to PHP 7.2:

```
Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /homepages/7/d544205487/htdocs/wp-content/themes/construction/template-agenda3.php on line 390


Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /homepages/7/d544205487/htdocs/wp-content/themes/construction/template-agenda3.php on line 413
```

**Line 413:**

```
if(sizeof($eventos[$day])>0) echo "</a>";
```

**Line 390:**

```
if(sizeof($eventos[$day])>0) echo "<a href='#openModal$day' style='text-decoration:none;'>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In PHP 7.2** 
sizeof Parameter must be an array or an object

**Line 413:**

```
if(is_array($eventos[$day]) && sizeof($eventos[$day]) > 0) echo "</a>";
```

**Line 390:**

```
if(is_array($eventos[$day]) && sizeof($eventos[$day])>0) echo "<a href='#openModal$day' style='text-decoration:none;'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand specific you want. But you can resolve the following:

Update plugin new version. If plugin not support then you can fix code:

```
if( is_array($eventos[$day]) && sizeof($eventos[$day])>0) echo "</a>";
```

```
if(is_array($eventos[$day]) && sizeof($eventos[$day])>0) echo "<a href='#openModal$day' style='text-decoration:none;'>"
```

Or, replace by method `count()`